# Why Win32 api _beginthreadex/CreateThread leaks when using CRT or not?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-leaks

I have the following function that is executed on a Thread created with _beginthreadex or CreateThread:

```cpp
static volatile LONG g_executedThreads = 0;
void executeThread(int v){
   //1. leaks: time_t tt = _time64(NULL);
   //2. leaks: FILETIME ft; GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);
   //3. no leak: SYSTEMTIME stm; GetSystemTime(&stm);

   InterlockedAdd(&g_executedThreads, 1); // count nr of executions
 }
```

When I uncomment any of lines **1.** (crt call) or **2.** (win 32 api call) the thread leaks and next calls of _begintreadex will fail( GetLastError -> return error (8) -> *Not enough storage is available to process this command*). 
Memory reported by Process Explorer, when _beginthreadex starts to fail:
Private **130 Mb**, Virtual **150 Mb**.

But if I uncomment only line **3.** (other win 32 api call) no leak happens, and no fail after 1 million of threads. Here Memory reported is Private **1.4 Mb**, Virtual **25 Mb**. And this version ran very fast (20 secs for 1 million threads vs the first one that took 60 secs for 30000).

I've tested ([see here the test code](https://gist.github.com/dnikku/a18d94ccdcd8434a5b87) ) with Visual Studio 2013, compiled x86 (debug and release) and ran on Win 8.1 x64; After creating 30000 of threads _beginthreadex starts failing (most of the calls); I want to mention that simultaneous running threads are under 100.

**Updated 2**:

My assumption of max 100 threads was based on console output (scheduled is aprox equal with completed) and [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) in Threads Tab did not report more then 10 threads_)
 Here is the console output (no WaitForSingleObject, original code):

```
step:0, scheduled:1, completed:1
step:5000, scheduled:5001, completed:5000
...
step:25000, scheduled:25001, completed:24999
step:30000, scheduled:30001, completed:30001
 _beginthreadex failed. err(8); errno(12). exiting ...
step:31701, scheduled:31712, completed:31710

rerun loop:
step:0, scheduled:31713, completed:31711
_beginthreadex failed. err(8); errno(12). exiting ...
step:6, scheduled:31719, completed:31716
```

Based on @SHR & @HarryJohnston suggestion I've scheduled 64 threads at once, and wait all to complete, ([see updated code here](https://gist.github.com/dnikku/ee891049764caecbba9c)), but the behaviour is  same. Note I've tried single thread once, but the fail happens sporadic. Also the Reserved Stack size is 64K!
Here is the new schedule function:

```
static unsigned int __stdcall _beginthreadex_wrapper(void *arg) {
    executeThread(1);
    return 0;
}
const int maxThreadsCount = MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS;
bool _beginthreadex_factory(int& step) {
    DWORD lastError = 0;

    HANDLE threads[maxThreadsCount];
    int threadsCount = 0;
    while (threadsCount < maxThreadsCount){
        unsigned int id;
        threads[threadsCount] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL,
            64 * 1024, _beginthreadex_wrapper, NULL, STACK_SIZE_PARAM_IS_A_RESERVATION, &id);
        if (threads[threadsCount] == NULL) {
            lastError = GetLastError();
            break;
        }
        else threadsCount++;
    }

    if (threadsCount > 0) {
        WaitForMultipleObjects(threadsCount, threads, TRUE, INFINITE);
        for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++) CloseHandle(threads[i]);
    }

    step += threadsCount;
    g_scheduledThreads += threadsCount;

    if (threadsCount < maxThreadsCount) {
        printf("    %03d sec: step:%d, _beginthreadex failed. err(%d); errno(%d). exiting ...\n", getLogTime(), step, lastError, errno);
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
```

Here is what is printed on Console:

```
000 sec: step:6400, scheduled:6400, completed:6400
003 sec: step:12800, scheduled:12800, completed:12800
007 sec: step:19200, scheduled:19200, completed:19200
014 sec: step:25600, scheduled:25600, completed:25600
022 sec: step:32000, scheduled:32000, completed:32000
023 sec: step:32358, _beginthreadex failed. err(8); errno(12). exiting ...
sleep 5 seconds
028 sec: step:32358, scheduled:32358, completed:32358
try to create 2 more times
028 sec: step:32361, _beginthreadex failed. err(8); errno(12). exiting ...
032 sec: step:32361, scheduled:32361, completed:32361
rerun loop: 1
036 sec: step:3, _beginthreadex failed. err(8); errno(12). exiting ...
sleep 5 seconds
041 sec: step:3, scheduled:32364, completed:32364
try to create 2 more times
041 sec: step:5, _beginthreadex failed. err(8); errno(12). exiting ...
045 sec: step:5, scheduled:32366, completed:32366
rerun loop: 2
056 sec: step:2, _beginthreadex failed. err(8); errno(12). exiting ...
sleep 5 seconds
061 sec: step:2, scheduled:32368, completed:32368
try to create 2 more times
061 sec: step:4, _beginthreadex failed. err(8); errno(12). exiting ...
065 sec: step:4, scheduled:32370, completed:32370
```

Any suggestion/info is welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a Windows expert but the problem is *almost surely* in code you have not shown.  I see that you have posted a *link* to your complete test program, but would you mind, first, cutting that program down to the *smallest possible program that still exhibits the memory leak*, and, second, editing that into the question?  (Unless you discover the problem during the cutting-down process, which happens.)

Comment: If `InterlockedAdd` function can terminate the thread in any way, than that could cause some memory leaks.

Comment: It's not a Win32 API. It is a [C library function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx).

Comment: SHR is right.  It isn't a leak, you just need to throttle the thread creation to limit the number of threads running simultaneously.  (You assert that no more than 100 threads are running at a time, but I don't see any way to confirm that.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston My assertion was based on what was print on console. scheduled and completed values do not differ to much.

Comment: @EJP I was refering to step2 [GetSystemTimeAsFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @zwol Actually the linked code is already cut-down, ~ 100 lines (excluding blank lines).

Comment: Is it the *smallest possible program that still exhibits the memory leak?*

Comment: @NicolaeDascalu: by the time the main thread has noticed the problem and retrieved the statistics, they'll already be out of date.

Comment: With your latest changes, I can no longer reproduce the problem on my Windows 8.1 machine.  It may be timing-sensitive.  However, the fact that the thread has exited does not necessarily mean that all the associated resources have been cleaned up, so I don't think it is safe in general to create very-short-lived threads that rapidly.  (I suspect you'll find that even a modest delay after each thread cycle will resolve the problem.)  Best practice is to create a thread pool when you start up, and only add or remove threads infrequently as necessary to address changes in load.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Ok, you could not reproduce failure, but the memory stay arround few MB?

Comment: OK, using Process Explorer: Virtual Size is highly variable (as makes sense with the thread stack reservations being created and destroyed) but does not appear to be exceeding 30,596K.  This is after 15 million threads.  I'll check again later today.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, I am agree with thread pool, but actually I just cut down the code from Emacs 24.5. I'm using Emacs + magit, magit uses create process api from Emacs + git.exe; for example a simple status command spawn 4 git.exe process that are completed in 1-2 secs; after a while of using magit (maybe spawn hundreds or thousand of processes) I received same error from magit/Emacs. Actually I've created a simple loop that run magit-status, and after 600 iteration (that took 5 minutes) I reproduced.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Continue: Debugging emacs (compiled with mingw32 on my Win 8.1 64bit) src I saw that on each new process spawned creates a new thread for monitoring avail_bytes on StandardOutput and signaling to the MainThread (an async mechanism). And the error originates from failing to create this thread (using CreateThread api).

Comment: Using Process Explorer, what DLLs are loaded into the process?  (Your repro code, I mean, not Emacs.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120.dll, Getting this info just observed some dll (hook) injected by the antivirus, ;) . Many thanks and see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you get it wrong. 
Take a look at this code:

```
int thread_func(void* p)
{
     Sleep(1000);
     return 0;
}
int main()
{
    LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE s = (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&thread_func;
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    {
        DWORD id;
        HANDLE h = CreateThread(NULL,0, s,NULL,0,&id); 
        WaitForSingleObject(h,INFINITE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A leaking thread will leak just because you calling it, so the wait doesn't chang a thing, but when you look at this in performance monitor, you'll see all lines are almost constant.

Now ask yourself, what will happen when I remove the `WaitForSingleObject`?

The creation of threads run much faster then the threads, so you reach the threads limit per proccess, or memory limit per process.
Note that if you are compiling for x86, memory is limited to 4GB but only 2GB is used for user mode memory and the other 2GB used for kernel mode memory. if you are using the default stack size (1MB) for thread, and the rest of the program doesn't use memory at all (it's never happen, since you have code...), then you are limited to 2000 threads. after the 2GB finished you can't create more threads until previous threads will over.

So, my conclusion is that you creating threads and don't wait, and after some period, no memory left for more threads.

You can check if this is the case with performance monitor and check the max threads per your process.

Comment: See my updates. And the big diff between your code and my is that my thread function is executed fast ... as mentioned (max treads in Process Explorer are under 10, and Peak Private Bytes: 131Mb)

Comment: Also, in first version (no Wait for thread to stop) I could schedule more then 30000 threads (each one with reserved stack 640K) without fail .. Using your assemption 30000 * 640K ~ 30 * 640M = 18Gb, this was no happend on x86 (max 2Gb user space). Based on my observation (Peak Memory = 130Mb) max nr of running threads = 200 ( 130 MB / 640K).

Comment: If you are not waiting for thread, you should also close the thread handle,  this will indicate that you don't care about its exit status, or waiting it, so the kernel won't save anything for you after thread exit.

Comment: Both the original and updated code close the handles correctly so far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

After uninstall the antivirus the failure could not be reproduced (even the code is run as fast as for the other scenario **3.**).